# Create Certificate... Greyed out in Developer Portal

Tags: ios, notifications, certificate, apple-push-notifications, push

So the option to Create Certificate for the Production SSL Certificate is greyed out for my app. The app is Pending Developer Release, could this be the cause? Is there a way to get this re-enabled?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I solved it. I just disabled push notifications and then re-enabled it and, while I have to redo the Development Certificate again, it allows me to do the Production again.